# JQuery Mobile App Resolution

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am developing an android app using JQM and PhoneGap . The app appears  good in low end devices but the letters  appear extremely small on high end tablets.I have tried modifying the viewport tag after browsing through so many sites.It would be very helpful if someone could give a resolution so that I can concentrate on functionality rather than the layout and resolution.

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS media queries to configure font styles based on device resolution.

Example:

```
@media screen and (max-width:600px) and (max-height:963px) {
 .fontClass {
        font-size: 38px;

    }
}
@media screen and (max-width:320px) and (max-height:568px) {
 .fontClass {
        font-size: 28px;

    }
}
```

Comment: Added this but didn't notice any considerable diff. I am using Sony Xperia Tablet(1280 X 800) . Is there any other method?

Comment: none I can imagine. but this should work. I have used this countless times. but remember these screen sizes are viewport sizes. you can check each divices viewport sizes here.[link](http://viewportsizes.com/) also this to work, avoid using any inline styles.